# Function order of $n\times \ln(1+{2\over n})$

Tags: functions

The sequence is:

$$a_n=n(ln(n+2)-ln(n))$$

I need to find the expression of $$a_n=\alpha+O(n^{-p})$$ where $$p$$ is an integer when $$n \to \infty $$. First I find $$\alpha$$ which is the limit of $$a_n$$ when $$n \to\infty$$. It is 2. Next I need to find an function in the form of $$n^{-p}$$ such that it would go at the same order. I know that $$ln(n+2)-ln(n)=ln(1+{2\over n})<{1\over n}$$. However, cannot figure out when $$n \times ln(n+2)-ln(n)=n\times ln(1+{2\over n})$$. Any hints?

Comment: $x - x^2/2 \leq ln(1 + x) \leq x$ for $x \geq 0$.

Comment: It seems like $$n^{-1}$$ or$$ n^{-2}$$ should be the appropriate order based on graphical depiction. I guess graphical approach is  better with my short experience in this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n=n\ln (1+\frac 2 n) \to 2$. Now consider $a_n-2=n[\ln (1+\frac 2 n) -\frac 2 n]\sim (-n)\frac 2 {n^{2}}=-\frac  2 n$ from the Taylor eapansion of $\ln (1+x)$.